# pyspark coalesce gives no space left on device

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, coalesce

I am trying to coalesce my dataframe into a single (part) file as below

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format('avro').save('file:///home/newbie/testdata/')
```

Initially this used to work fine but as the size of data grows from hundreds to millions of rows in dataframe, I am getting the below error

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

This is because of the spark temp space (default: `/tmp/`) is running out of memory. So I changed it to `/local/scratch/` and it working fine now.

But I am not very much convinced with the approach of providing `spark.local.dir` to some location with more space. It may blow up anytime.

So is there any way that I can write the dataframe into a single file without loading all the data into the memory?

In other words, with minimal usage of (heap) memory, dump the rows to persistent storage (disk)

Comment: why you are not increasing the coalesce(1) size ? When the data is huge , 1 partition is some point of time will not be able to hold the entire data

Comment: because I need a single file which has to be passed on to the downstream APIs (non Spark).

Comment: Don't think there's a way to do that consistently in spark without getting into memory issues. Another thing you can try is using a separate process to merge and append the part files into one big file later.